# I change my computer and cloned my CodeIgniter 4 project from github, this happened

Tags: project, clone, codeigniter-4

**fatal error**: uncaught error: class "psr\log\loglevel" not found in c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\app\config\exceptions.php:76 stack trace: #0 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\common.php(206): codeigniter\config\factories::__callstatic('config', array) #1 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\config\services.php(264): config('exceptions') #2 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\config\baseservice.php(252): codeigniter\config\services::exceptions(null, null, null, false) #3 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\config\baseservice.php(193): codeigniter\config\baseservice::__callstatic('exceptions', array) #4 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\config\services.php(261): codeigniter\config\baseservice::getsharedinstance('exceptions', null, null, null) #5 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\config\baseservice.php(252): codeigniter\config\services::exceptions() #6 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\system\codeigniter.php(186): codeigniter\config\baseservice::__callstatic('exceptions', array) #7 c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\index.php(55): codeigniter\codeigniter->initialize() #8 {main} thrown in **c:\xampp\htdocs\inventariotio\app\config\exceptions.php** on line **76**

.-.....................

Comment: Are you using the same version of CodeIgniter? check your both composer.lock (former and current)

Comment: Do you have done with `composer update`?